# The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Apache Error

Tags: regex, apache, ssi

I am using apache2.2 on windows environment. I have ssi to be include the content such as :

```
<!--#include virtual="/content/app/en/jcr:content/test.html" -->
```

Its giving an error below :

```
[Fri Jan 29 14:53:09 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /content/app/en/myPage.html HTTP/1.1 to file
[Fri Jan 29 14:53:09 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] unable to include "/content/app/en/jcr:content/test.html" in parsed file
```

I have tried using /:, but no effect. On browser its giving error `:[an error occurred while processing this directive]`

Comment: Do some one has any idea about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not allow `:` in its folder names so apache is unable to map it to a file on disk. This should not happen on linux.

If possible, use `_jcr_content` instead of `jcr:content` in the above path.

Comment: I'd recommend to wrap ":" with backticks for better readability: `:` :)